# Implementing protocols on top of raw sockets and using O_DIRECT

Tags: bash, sockets, linux-kernel, network-protocols

So, I am trying to make a toy (bash?) implementation of TCP on top of raw sockets, to better understand the protocol.

I understand that /dev/raw is deprecated in favor of O_DIRECT (why?) and is not enabled in my kernel.

```
$ zgrep -i raw /proc/config.gz
CONFIG_IP_NF_RAW=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_RAW=m
CONFIG_SERIO_RAW=m
# CONFIG_RAW_DRIVER is not set
CONFIG_SND_RAWMIDI=m
CONFIG_SND_RAWMIDI_SEQ=m
CONFIG_HIDRAW=y
CONFIG_USB_SERIAL_SIERRAWIRELESS=m
CONFIG_USB_GADGET_VBUS_DRAW=2
# CONFIG_LINE6_USB_RAW is not set
CONFIG_ATH6KL_HTC_RAW_INTERFACE=y
```

I cannot find information on how to send data without linux's TCP implementation using O_DIRECT which is what I guess I should use.

Comment: O_DIRECT is for honest files and block devices only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an informative paper on raw sockets in FreeBSD 7.0 and Linux 2.6.

> SOCK_RAW Demystified
>
> SOCK_RAW Demystified is a paper I wrote about explaining the implementation of the raw sockets mechanism in the kernels of FreeBSD 7.0 and Linux 2.6. It delves into network internals showing the details of this powerful socket type and how it works behind the scene.
>
> http://sock-raw.org/papers.html

If you do not have `/dev/tcp` in Bash, you may want to look at Richard Stevens' sock program (http://www.icir.org/christian/sock.html).